# calendarView is not shown the correct months

Tags: java, android, calendarview

The calendarView it always shows a month before the chosen one, example: I choose 20/02/2002, calendarView min returns 20/01/2002.
Como eu faço pra que seja recuperado ao clicar o mês correto ?

My calendarView:

```
calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView calendarView, int year, int month, int day) {
                String data = dia+"/"+mes+"/"+ano;
                Toast.makeText(PagamentoActivity.this, data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Do not know what's the language for the last sentence

Comment: @lucumt _Do not know what's the language for the last sentence_ It's Portuguese. Do you not know about [Google translate](https://translate.google.com/) ? It will try to auto detect the language for you.

Comment: Do you know about [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) ?

Comment: @Abra Unfortunately,google services are not available in China!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the month starts with 0 and not 1, try using this it will work for you:

```
calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView calendarView, int year, int month, int day) {
            String data = day+"/"+(month+1)+"/"+year;
            Toast.makeText(PagamentoActivity.this, data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public interface OnDateChangeListener {

    /**
     * Called upon change of the selected day.
     *
     * @param view The view associated with this listener.
     * @param year The year that was set.
     * @param month The month that was set [0-11].
     * @param dayOfMonth The day of the month that was set.
     */
    void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth);
}
```

month index start with zero